# React Pixi responsive stage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pixi.js

I am trying to make my stage responsive however i am not quite sure how to do it when using the react library:

```
<Stage options={{backgroundColor: 0xffffff, radius: 1, width: 736, height: 414}}>

    <Sprite image="baseBike.png" x={100} y={100}/>

    <Sprite image={this.state.saddle.image} x={this.state.saddle.x} y={this.state.saddle.y}
            scale={{x: this.state.saddle.scale.x, y: this.state.saddle.scale.y}}/>


    <Sprite image={this.state.steering.image} x={this.state.steering.x}
            y={this.state.steering.y}
            scale={{x: this.state.steering.scale.x, y: this.state.steering.scale.y}}/>
    <Sprite image="circle.png" x={290} y={90} scale={{x: 1, y: 1}}
            interactive={true}
            pointerdown={() => {
                this.toogleMenu("saddle");
            }}
    />
    <Sprite image="circle.png" x={530} y={130} scale={{x: 1, y: 1}}
            interactive={true}
            pointerdown={() => {
                this.toogleMenu("steering");
            }}
    />

</Stage>
```

Does anyone know how to make sure that the `Sprites` and `Stage` is responsive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to achieve that but in my experience resizing your objects separately will prove to be a great pain when your application starts to grow bigger.

The easiest and consistent way I've found so far is to use the concept of containers as much as possible.

E.g. your stage is a container. When adding sprites or whatever other objects, they will be positioned and scaled relative to the stage they are added to.

Try to apply any scales and positions directly to the stage only. Take a look at the article below:
https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html

It offers a few options for resizing the canvas only, which will take effect to it's children as well. Hope it helps